# Confused about Android BroadcastReceiver & Service

Tags: android, service, xamarin, broadcastreceiver

I have some code which wants to track available Wifi network, regardless whether the app is working or not.

Based on some sample I found on the web I do the following:

1. Register an appropriate *WakefulBroadcastReceiver*
2. In the receiver fire an *Intent* which starts one of my *IntentService*
3. Finally in the service analyze the results and store them in a static variable (should be accessible to the whole process).

Hopefully my whole application runs in one process (I think I saw a flag to specify that one day.. not sure where..)

Now I got a few questions:

- Why not do the work in the receiver, why start a service?
- Why use a Wakeful receiver, instead of just a plain receiver? Particularly if the work is redirected to a service
- Would my service and my app's activity be in the same process? Kind of necessary for sharing data via static variables...

Answer (score 0):

Okay a couple of things. If you want to communicate with the service, you need to use a ServiceConnection and connect to it by "binding". If you bind to a service *after* it has been started, then the service will persist in the background outside the lifecycle of the activity.

To bind to the service:

```
    public ServiceConnection mServiceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
        // initialize the service and bind to the tracking service
        YourService.YourBinder binder = (YourService.YourBinder) service;
        mService = binder.getService();
        mBound = true;
        }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
        }
    };
```

The Binder is nested in your service and used to return an instance of the service. So, you could have a service that records your location in the background, and only communicates with your activity when it is running.

So, your service would not be in the same process -- it's a totally different thread.

You can store your data in the service itself, and access it by 
putting a public getData() method in your service; you can access this method using the mService variable as it is assigned above.

Finally, if you want to communicate from the service to the activity, then you would send an intent to the BroadcastReceiver.

Comment: `Finally, if you want to communicate from the service to the activity, then you would send an intent to the BroadcastReceiver.` not really, as you said: "If you want to communicate with the service, you need to use a ServiceConnection and connect to it by binding" - so use binding - it can perfectly work in both directions